# In MYSQL, Is it possible to use the LEAST function with column_names?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, information-schema

I am wondering if it is possible to integrate, in MYSQL, the functions LEAST / GREATEST together with SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.table name. If possible, it would save me a lot of time.

The code i current have is simplified below:

```
SELECT 
    tb.date,
    LEAST(tb.test_0, tb.test_1, tb.test_2) AS min_value, 
FROM mySchema.myTable AS tb;
```

This code works. However, I don't want to have to write down all the 'tb.test_', so I am working on a query using LIKE function. The following query produces as output a table with all the column_names of my db.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mySchema'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'
    and COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'test_%';
```

Therefore, I was expecting to combine both functions and produce something like:

```
SELECT 
    tb.date,
    LEAST(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mySchema'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'
    and COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'test_%'
    ) AS min_value, 
FROM mySchema.myTable AS tb;
```

Comment: You would need dynamic SQL for this, which is to say you would need to write code which queries information schema and then builds the MySQL query string which you want to execute.

Comment: *I don't want to have to write down all the 'tb.test_', so I am working on a query using LIKE function.* This is one-time work. Copy the output of your query to `information_schema.COLUMNS` into some text editor, combine it to needed SQL code part, then paste into LEAST arguments list of your query.